# Is there a way I can avoid adding System.ComponentModel namspace when using enum?

Tags: asp.net, enums

I have an extension method that allows me to add a Description attribute to my enums.

A typical enum looks like this:

```
public enum Legal
{
    [Description("INVALID!")]
    None = 0,
    [Description("general-terms")]
    General = 1,
    [Description("competition-terms")]
    Competition = 2,
    [Description("privacy-policy")]
    Privacy = 3,
    [Description("cookie-policy")]
    Cookies = 4
}
```

When using the enum (and having added its namespace), I still find I need to add the System.ComponentModel namespace everywhere I use it. Is there any way around this?

Here's the extension method:

```
    public static string Description(this Enum @this)
    {
        @this.ThrowNull("@this");

        var memInfo = @this.GetType().GetMember(@this.ToString());

        if (memInfo.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
        {
            var attribute = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attribute.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
                return ((DescriptionAttribute)attribute[0]).Description;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the description attribute, you have to reference it's namespace. However, I rarely use that attribute. Simple intellisense (XML) comments work fine from a code documentation standpoint, IMO.

```
[Flags]
public enum PetTypes
{
    /// <summary>An option for cats!</summary>
    Cats = 1,

    /// <summary>An option for dogs!</summary>
    Dogs = 2

    /// <summary>Bill Murray style</summary>
    MassHysteria = 3
}
```

Comment: I use the descriptions where I need to enhance the normal description. Typically where I'm woking with a fixed list provided by a third part, but which whould be an enum.